# Drupal 7 MultiStep Form

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to implement the Multistep tutorial (Step 9) from http://drupal.org/node/717750 in Drupal 7, however in the following function

```
function my_module_my_form_new_name($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['storage']['new_name'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; // Will cause the default submit function
                                 // to be skipped.
}
```

I just cant set the `$form_state['storage']['new_name'] = TRUE;`
therefore i can't catch it in :

```
 if (empty($form_state['storage']['new_name'])) {
    $form['new_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Add another name',
      '#validate' => array('my_module_my_form_new_name'),
    );
  }
```

I can however declare it in the beginning of the function, which can be executed fine. So how can I set it in Drupal 7?

Comment: You're probably better off looking at a Drupal 7 example instead of Drupal 6. The [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) has many form examples including multi-step.

Comment: Thanks, will do... however why I cant pass the value of a variable $form_state['storage']['new_name'] to the step 2?

Comment: Hopefully someone can answer that for you. I haven't read the tutorial you linked to, just noticed it was for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helpful links for creating multi steps form are https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-there-any-examples-of-setting-up-multistep-forms http://drupal.org/node/717750, and http://drupal.org/project/examples.

I practiced multi step forms by getting the code of the form tutorial from http://drupal.org/project/examples, and added further steps; it works excellently fine for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Since this is a quite old question  I've already found an answer to it, which is actually similar to yours.

Comment: its good to hear