# drupal 7 on submission of form respective form should open

Tags: forms

in my form i have to show two radio button and one submit button,please see below my front form is like this:

candidate(radio)

organization(radio)

submit button.

my requirement is that

if user click/check on candidate radio button and click on submit then candidate form should be open on candidate page.

or

if user click/check on organization radio button and click on submit then organization form should be open on organization page.

my code:

```
<?php
/**@file
*donation.module*/
/**
*Implements hook_menu()*/
function donation_menu(){
$items['donate'] = array(
'title' => 'Donate',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('donation_donate_form'),
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'access callback' => TRUE,
);    
return $items;
}
/**
*Implements hook_form().
*/
function donation_donate_form($form, &$form_submit){
/*the options to display in our form radio buttons*/
$options = array
'candidate' => t('Candidate'),    
'organization' => t('Organization'),
);
$form['officials'] = array(    
'#title' => t('OFFICIALS'),    
'#type' => 'radios',
'#options' => $options,    
'#default_value' => $options['candidate'],
);
$form['name'] = array(
'#title' => t('NAME'),
'#type' => 'textfield',    
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#value' => t('PROCEED'),
'#type' => 'submit',
);
return $form;
}
```

Comment: This question is probably better answered on the web apps page.

Comment: How are you displaying the form? You could just make your form redirect to the appropriate form depending on value submitted. Or you could use a multistep  form as outlined in in this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17021/drupal-7-multistep-form

Comment: The examples module has an example of a mutistep form (wizard): https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: Thanks 2pha, i have downloaded example module and working on it.